# Can I use System.Web.UI.Page in console application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to test a function which is in a web page. Do I have way to use System.Web.UI.Page in a console application and put something in Session and test this way?

I created a test class and to inherit the Page but I could not put Session in it. When I type "myPage." as show below,  I do not see anything come out after "."

```
<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim myPage = New System.Web.UI.Page
    myPage.
End Class
```

Please help!

Update: Below code seemed to pass the compiler

```
<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest2
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TestCheckRules()
        Dim myPage As testWebPage = New testWebPage
        myPage.testSession()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class testWebPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub testSession()
        Dim firstName As String = "John"
        Dim lastName As String = "Smith"
        Dim city As String = "Seattle"
        Session("FirstName") = firstName
        Session("LastName") = lastName
        Session("City") = city
    End Sub
```

End Class

Then when I ran I got the following error:
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish.  Why does your unit test inherit from `Page`?  A unit test and a web page are *very different things*.  Why are you creating an instance of `Page`?  There's nothing in `Page` that you need to test, that's framework code.  If you have your own page class then create an instance of *your class*.  And no, a unit test has no active HTTP context.  In order to unit test your web application you need to separate testable code from web-dependent code.

Comment: So you mean, I have to have a web site running with some pages in order to test the webpage code. If I can manually setup an active HTTP context then I can test a webpage without a web environment right? My question is : is this possible to test a web page without setup a website. This may be strange to some, but the situation is I have a website which is old, and it is big, I am trying to test just part of the code in one page.

Comment: You can test code, but you can't test "the website" without an actual, well, website.  In order to unit test the code you'll need to separate the testable components from the non-testable components.  If you want to test the whole thing as one black box then you would need a running instance of the application and you'd interact with that.

Comment: In other words, write your business logic in a http-agnostic assembly. Then reference that assembly from unit test and execute code. Same thing for the website - reference that same assembly from website and only make calls to it from your page methods. Page is really there to execute in ASP.net stack and not designed to work outside of that.